# Images in ie are pixelated

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, image-processing, photoshop

I've uploaded png images to a website, and they appear perfect in firefox, chrome and safari but they look horrible in ie.  I have saved the files from photoshop, and they have a feature under image size that gives you the option to have the image as: bicubic automatic, bicubic sharper, bicubic smoother, bicubic, bilinear and nearest neighbor.  Would any of these help?

**html:**

```
<ul class="social">
  <li><a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/+ToadhallcottagesCoUk/posts"><img onmouseout=this.src='/images/googleplusgrey-flat.png' onmouseover=this.src='/images/googleplus-flat.png' src="/images/googleplusgrey-flat.png" width="38" height="38" alt="Toad Hall Cottages Google Plus Page"</a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com/thcottages"><img onmouseout=this.src='/images/twittergrey-flat.png' onmouseover=this.src='/images/twitter-flat.png' src="/images/twittergrey-flat.png" width="38" height="38" alt="Toad Hall Cottages on Twitter" /></a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/holidaycottages"><img <img onmouseout=this.src='/images/facebookgrey-flat.png' onmouseover=this.src='/images/facebook-flat.png'  src="/images/facebookgrey-flat.png" width="38" height="38" alt="Toad Hall Cottages Facebook page"/></a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.pinterest.com/thcottages/"><img <img onmouseout=this.src='/images/pinterestgrey-flat.png' onmouseover=this.src='/images/pinterest-flat.png' src="/images/pinterestgrey-flat.png" width="38" height="38" alt="Toad Hall Cottages Facebook page" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

**css:**

```
img.icon { 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  margin-right: 8px; 
  margin-left: 2px;
  image-rendering:optimizeSpeed;             /* Legal fallback */
  image-rendering:-moz-crisp-edges;          /* Firefox        */
  image-rendering:-o-crisp-edges;            /* Opera          */
  image-rendering:-webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Safari         */
}
```

Comment: horrible browser will render things horribly.....you mind sharing your css and html so that we can help!! :)

Comment: You should save the images on the server in the dimensions required by the website - e.g. if your header is displayed as 800x100px your image should be exactly 800x100px as well.

Comment: i have uploaded css and html

Comment: You don't need to use `Javascript` to accomplish image rollovers. Instead you should have a look at sprite images, and do it all in the `CSS`. This also cuts down the number of HTTP requests the browser needs to make. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/basic-link-rollover-as-css-sprite/

Comment: my images are 150px x 150px and then reduced in size on the web page, would that not give it better resolution @Njol?

Comment: Totally not related to question, but hey @NoobEditor, I love that you're using `:)` and other smileys, you're just like me dude! :P

Comment: thanks for the roll over link @NickR, but surely the same problem with image resolution happen?

Comment: @totneschap Yes it probably would, you could try this fix however: `img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }` from http://blog.mirthlab.com/2009/04/22/smooth-image-scaling-in-ie-via-css/

Comment: excellent, that worked @NickR as well as Njol suggestion. Do you want to put this as a question so I can mark it as a correct answer?

Comment: why the edit @NoobEditor, was it poorly laid out?

Comment: @totneschap : no, because any future visitor to this question might find a better formatted question, a good experience!! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The old IE method is:

```
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
```

This is poorly documented.

Comment: This issue can be solved by jQuery plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965904/ie-thumbnail-pixelation-when-high-resolution-image-is-set-to-small-size

Comment: Imagine if the OP asked for a jQuery solution^

Comment: Isn't this the default interpolation? I can't see a difference between this and nothing (in IE 11).

Comment: Hi @BarryCap, no – this feature was only available in IE7 & 8 – it should not be necessary for IE9 and upwards.